# Putting PHP data inside a div with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, mysqli

Hello I am making an app with HTML5/Javascript, and I want to get some data out of it and put all the data in a div. I am totally new into AJAX and have not very much experience with AJAX. How can I read the .PHP file from an URL and put all the data into a HTML page?

This is my **.PHP** file:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM phpxtra_leden ORDER BY last_name ASC"
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

   echo "<tr>";

   echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['gender'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['last_name'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['birth_date'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['member_since'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td><a href='lid_bewerk.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>bewerk</a></td>";
   echo "<td><a href='lid_verwijder.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>verwijder</a></td>";

   echo "</tr>";

}
```

Comment: Have you done any [AJAX Tutorials](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)? You need to start there.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to Stack Overflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: As long as you use jQuery you cand take a look at [jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) or [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) methods

Comment: And where's your ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh... guess if no-one else is going to help you...

Ok so you have your php file like you mentioned in your question. Now you need a ajax function to call that php file to retrieve the data.

Add this javascript to the page you want to make the request from:

```
$(function(){
    $.post('path/to/php/file.php', {some_variable: the_variable_you_want_to_send}, function(data, result, xhr){
        if(result == 'success') {
            // the data you requested will be inside data
            $('.some_div_class').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I literally don't understand why I get down votes... but again thanks for helping me out!!

Comment: By the way is it possible to get call a PHP file in an URL like: domain.com/phpfile.php

Comment: @BerkBalik Yes just replace the 'path/to/php/file.php' with the url